# set value from 0 to 100 for slider in cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, slider, cypress

I want to drag my slider from different position on every run.
My code is

```
it.only("Changing slider", () => {
        cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .element-list > .menu-list > #item-3').click() //Slider
        cy.get(".range-slider")
        .invoke("val",0-100)
        .trigger("change")
        .click({ force: true })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to inject a random value into `input.value`.

With a range 0 - 36, `Math.random() * 36` gives you a value in that range.

```js
it("Changing slider", () => {
  cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .element-list > .menu-list > #item-3').click() //Slider

  const randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 36)

  cy.get(".range-slider")
    .invoke("val", randomVal)
    .trigger("change")
    .click({ force: true })
})
```

BTW - your question title says `0 - 100` but the sample code says `0 - 36` so whichever is your maximum value, substitute it into the code above.